# Add stdout = TRUE to R's system2 command and receive warning. Why?

Tags: r, system2

I require the number of Firefox processes running on Linux (Ubuntu) be stored in a variable in an R script. By itself the system2 command I use seems to work. However, when I add `stdout = TRUE` to capture the info in a character vector I get a warning. Why the warning?

```
system2(command = "ps", args = "aux | grep [f]irefox -c")
# 0

system2(command = "ps", args = "aux | grep [f]irefox -c", stdout = TRUE)

Warning message:
In system2(command = "ps", args = "aux | grep [f]irefox -c", stdout = TRUE) :
  running command ''ps' aux | grep [f]irefox -c' had status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ef` instead of `aux` as the argument to `ps`. `aux` for BSD and `ef` and variants for standard syntex, as per `man ps`.

```
system2('ps', '-ef | grep [f]irefox -c', stdout = TRUE)
[1] "12"
```

Comment: How do I capture the output in a character vector? If I say x <- system2... the value of x is one while the statement returns zero (at least on my machine at this time).

Comment: I changed the answer.

Comment: I still get the same warning as my original question.

Comment: That is surprising. I wander how our systems might differ.